# How can I lemmatize list of lists in python using spacy?

Tags: python, spacy

I have a list of lists that contain words that need to be lemmatized. I am getting an error that says string is required instead of list because I am using Spacy.

If I convert to string i.e. `nlp(str(list_1))`, then the list separators(like: "," and "[") are tokenized and included in my output.

How can I lemmatize the items in my list of lists and get it back to the same form i.e. list of lists?

The words that need to be lemmatized could be anywhere in the list of lists.

I would like something like this:

Input:

`[["flower", "grows", "garden"], [["boy", "running", "playground"]]`

Output:

`[["flower", "grow", "garden"], ["boy", "run", "playground"]]`

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
list_1 = [["flower", "grows", "garden"], ["boy", "running", "playground"]]

for item in nlp(str(list_1)):
      print(item.lemma_)
```

Answer (score 4):

I would split this task into the following parts:

### 1. Creation of nlp object and your text

You have already done it but for posterity:

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
words = [["flower", "grows", "garden"], ["boy", "running", "playground"]]
```

### 2. Get length of each list

We need to have a length of each list so we can later iterate over it (in order to reshape outputs). Using [numpy.cumsum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) we can create an array which will allows us to do so in `O(n)` time.

```
# remember about importing numpy
lengths = np.cumsum([0] + list(map(len, words)))
print(lengths)
```

This would give us the following array (for your case):

```
[0 3 6]
```

We will later use ranges created from this array, e.g. tokens `[0:3]` constitute first array and tokens `[3:6]` constitute the second one.

### 3. Flatten your array and create Doc

```
flat_words = [item for sublist in words for item in sublist]
doc = spacy.tokens.Doc(nlp.vocab, words=flat_words)
```

It's better to pass `flat_words` as list so `spacy` doesn't have to perform unnecessary tokenization operation.

### 4. Iterate over spans

Lastly iterate over [`spacy.tokens.Span`](https://spacy.io/api/span) objects, over their tokens and add those (`lemmatized` of course) to the list.

```
lemmatized = []
# Iterate starting with 1
for index in range(1, len(lengths)):
    # Slice doc as described in the first point, so [0:3] and [3:6]
    span = doc[lengths[index - 1] : lengths[index]]
    # Add lemmatized tokens as list to the outer list
    lemmatized.append([token.lemma_ for token in span])
```

Output of `print(lemmatized)` would be as you wanted:

```
[['flower', 'grow', 'garden'], ['boy', 'run', 'playground']]
```

### 5. Whole code

Just to make it easier for you, whole code below:

```
import numpy as np
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
words = [["flower", "grows", "garden"], ["boy", "running", "playground"]]

lengths = np.cumsum([0] + list(map(len, words)))
print(lengths)


flat_words = [item for sublist in words for item in sublist]
doc = spacy.tokens.Doc(nlp.vocab, words=flat_words)

lemmatized = []
# Iterate starting with 1
for index in range(1, len(lengths)):
    # Slice doc as described in the first point, so [0:3] and [3:6]
    span = doc[lengths[index - 1] : lengths[index]]
    # Add lemmatized tokens as list to the list
    lemmatized.append([token.lemma_ for token in span])

print(lemmatized)
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are dealing with a list of lists, you can join the items in the lists and then use `nlp()`. Next, get the lemma for each item in these. To return a lists of lists again, just lemmatize the item at the index where the item occurs.

```
for item in list_1:
    doc = nlp(' '.join(item))    
    for indexer,i in enumerate(doc):
        item[indexer] = i.lemma_
print(list_1)
#Output:
[['flower', 'grow', 'garden'], ['boy', 'run', 'playground']]
```

Comment: Thanks! But how do I put them back to their original form i.e. list of lists form?

Comment: @amanb It's pretty inefficient to create `spacy.tokens.Doc` `i` times and perform unneeded tokenization after each step, isn't it?